# utilizar peticiones $http anidadas angular 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic, sqlite

Hola buenos días tengo un proyecto con `Ionic 1` donde tengo que realizar diferentes consultas y muchas peticiones en un solo click (al sincronizar)
donde obtengo primero un listado de personas y sobre el resultado que obtengo
voy consultado todos sus datos y a la vez enviado toda su información

```
for(var i=0; i<resutl.length; i++){
    send(resutl, id_con_person);
    //aqui llamo a la funcion send que a la vez esta funcion llama otras 
      funciones 
}
```

¿De que manera puedo hacer que se realice de manera sincrona con angular 1 o cual es la manera coorrecta de hacer este procedimiento ?
se los agradecería mucho, saludos.

```
function send(resutl, id_con_person){
query="SELECT * FROM identification where id_con_person=?";
 $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query,[this_idPerson]).then(

var req = {method: 'POST',url: base_url_services, 
           data:$httpParamSerializer({xxxx.stringify(xxx)}),
           headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                                }

$http(req).success(function(data, status, headers, config) 
{
    if(data[0].status==="SUCCESS"){
            insertXXX(data[0].xxx)
            insertXXX(data[0].xxxx);
    }else{}

}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) 
{
   alert("Error");
  });introducir el código aquí

}
,function(error){
  alert(JSON.stringify(error));
});

}


function insertXXX(){
query="SELECT * FROM xxxx ";
 $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query,[]).then(

var req = {method: 'POST',url: base_url_services, 
           data:$httpParamSerializer({xxxx.stringify(xxx)}),
           headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                                }

$http(req).success(function(data, status, headers, config) 
{
    if(data[0].status==="SUCCESS"){

    }else{}

}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) 
{
   alert("Error");
  });introducir el código aquí

}
,function(error){
  alert(JSON.stringify(error));
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que las llamadas a servicios `REST` son asíncronas. Pero puedes anidar llamadas con una `promise` usando `then` en lugar de `success`

Aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```
$http.get(req).then(function(response) {
     // success 
     if(response.data[0].status==="SUCCESS"){
         $http.get(req2).then(function(response) {

         });
     }else{}

}, function(response) {
    // error handler
});
```

Puedes ver una explicación en inglés sobre la diferencia entre "then" y "success" [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385278/angular-httppromise-difference-between-success-error-methods-and-thens-a/16385350#16385350)